# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping, one to one relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have relationship one to one

```
  public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Annotation { get; set; }
        public virtual File File { get; set; }
        public int? SeriesId { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
        public Book()
        {
            Comments = new List<Comment>();
            Authors = new List<Author>();
            Genres = new List<Genre>();
        }
    }

 public class File
    {
       [Key,ForeignKey("Book")]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
        public virtual  Book Book { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to transfer data to  classes:

```
public class BookDO
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Annotation { get; set; }
    public virtual FileDO File { get; set; }

}


public class FileDO
    {

        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
        public virtual BookDO Book { get; set; }
    }
```

in such way:

```
 var books = Database.Books.GetAll().ToList();
            Mapper.Initialize(cf => cf.CreateMap<Book, BookDO>());
            return Mapper.Map<List<Book>, List<BookDO>>(books);
```

but i'm getting Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
File -> FileDO
Domain.File -> BusinessLogic.Data_Objects.FileDO
Maybe i need to initialize one more mapper to map File to FileDO or modify existing mapper configuration? help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you also need to create a map for `File` -> `FileDo`. This map must be configured for the same mapper as used for `Book` -> `BookDo`.

It is good practice to wrap your mapping configuration into an `AutoMapper.Profile`:

```
using AutoMapper;
public class BookMappingProfile: Profile {
    public BookMappingProfile() {
        CreateMap<Book, BookDo>();
        CreateMap<File, FileDo>();
    }
}
```

And then initialize the mapper with these profiles:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { 
    cfg.AddProfile<BookMappingProfile>(); 
    cfg.AddProfile<MyOtherProfile>();
});
```